# Setting flags globally in expect scripts, such as nocase

Tags: scripting, tcl, expect

I have a few expect scripts that call `-nocase -re` on every instance of the expect command. For example:

```
expect {
    -nocase "this" { do_this_stuff }
    -nocase "that" { do_that_stuff }
    -nocase "others" { do_other_stuff }
}
```

I would like to optimise my scripts by calling options once globally.

I have searched through the [man](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html) pages and the [wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/string+compare) and the [man](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/string.htm) pages for Tcl itself and have found no reference of a method for doing this.

Is it possible to set expect flags globally at the start of a script that applies to every subsequent call of `expect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a better way to implement mrcalvin's suggestion:

```
proc expect_nocase_re {pattern_action_list} {
    # global spawn_id   ;# this _may_ be needed
    set myargs [list]
    for {pattern body} $pattern_action_list {
        lappend myargs -nocase -re $pattern $body
    }
    uplevel 1 expect $myargs
}
# usage
expect_nocase_re {
    this { do_this } 
    that { do_that } 
    other { do_other }
}
```

This expects that you're passing a list containing **only** pattern/action pairs. Don't use other `expect` options, like `-glob`, `-exact`, etc. It should be OK to pass an odd-numbered list, where the last element is a pattern with not action body.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure that the body to `expect` is an ordinary list. Have you tested what you've got there?

Comment: no I haven't. I missed the proviso that the custom proc precludes other arguments for each pattern, like `-glob`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are ways of doing so, I am not Expect-savy, but you could also define your `expect` command:

```
proc my.expect args {
    uplevel [list expect \
         -nocase "this" { do_this_stuff } \
         -nocase "that" { do_that_stuff } \
         -nocase "others" { do_other_stuff } \
         {*}$args]
}
```

This assumes that you deliberately use `my.expect` at each occasion.

You may also want to replace `expect` in-place, by using [`interp hide`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/interp.htm#M18) or an explicit [`rename`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/rename.htm):

```
interp hide {} expect
proc expect args {
    uplevel [list interp invokehidden {} expect \
         -nocase "this" { do_this_stuff } \
         -nocase "that" { do_that_stuff } \
         -nocase "others" { do_other_stuff } \
         {*}$args]
 }
```